# Command Line SSH restart Mac OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: mac, command-line, ssh, osx-mountain-lion, sshd

How can I restart the SSH service via the command line on Mac OSX Mountain Lion please?

Using `ps aux | grep 'ssh'`, I was able to deduce that the process is most likely `/usr/sbin/sshd`.

From here I searched the [sshd documentation](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8) for references to 'restart' but found none.

I don't know what my next step should be.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? If it's something like reloading the sshd config, you don't need to -- launchd starts a new sshd process on demand when an incoming connection is received, which means that the config is automatically reread for each new connection. OTOH, if you're trying to change the listener settings, those are controlled by launchd *not* the sshd config at all (see [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.macosx.admin/20553)).

Comment: This was just one test of debugging a password request from supposedly passwordless ssh using public keys. Turns out the thing I has missed was to turn off StrictMode

Answer (score 67, accepted):

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/194886/134295) to a similar question on ServerFault. The command should be the same in Mountain Lion.

> You can stop the service using the 'unload' subcommand.
>
> ```
> sudo launchctl unload  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
> ```

---

Update suggested by @MattClark: To restart the service use `load` after `unload`:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

Note that existing SSH sessions will be terminated, so you need to run this independent of the current user session.

Comment: This one gets me `launchctl: Error unloading: com.openssh.sshd`

Comment: You are correct, I did misread this, that was my fault. However, this also did not answer the question as it was asked.

Comment: You can run this in one go with C-x C-e (C stands for Control). Paste it into the terminal, then C-x C-c to execute the emacs kill command, which will prompt you to save. I did this remotely and it did not kill my connection... given your config is correct.

Answer (score 126):

There is no reason to 'unload' the sshd service, when instead you can just 'Stop' the sshd service. It will restart on it's own.

```
sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
```

Comment: on moutain lion: `launchctl stop error: No such process`

Comment: @RickyA: Worked fine on OSX Mavericks

Comment: Doesn't work here (`launchctl stop error: No such process`)

Comment: You need to ```sudo``` since that is how it is launched.  Compare the running daemons/agents ```launchctl list | grep -i openssh``` vs ```sudo launchctl list | grep -i openssh```. For reference read the launchctl [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html)

Comment: This no longer works in OS X Yosemite, attempting to stop sshd (as root) results in exit status of 3, and the service continues running.

Comment: Yes it works for me on Yosemite.  Have you enabled 'Remote Login' in Preferences->Sharing?  You need to confirm it is running with launchctl:  ```sudo launchctl list | grep -i sshd```. If not, perhaps you started it some other way?

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Comment: On Mac verson `13` after stopping, it does not (re)start automatic it seems because `ps -ef` does not show `sshd`. But `launchctl list` as put by @glenschler shows `com.openssh.sshd`. So it must work.

Comment: On my mac (macOS 13.5, m1), this command can be successfully executed, but the service will still be running, I have to disable it through the GUI.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't confirm Ansgar's answer worked as there were no messages / obvious signs though I'm confident it did.

I also found `killall sshd` which kills and restarts sshd processes with the disadvantage that any connections are stopped.

Answer (score 2):

You can restart `sshd` on macOS by running:

```
sudo launchctl kickstart -k system/com.openssh.sshd
```

This command slightly improves on `launchctl stop` because this does not rely on `sshd` automatically starting after you stop it.  However, similar to `launchctl stop` this preserves existing `ssh` connections.

Answer (score 0):

The question and answers seen here are too old (2012-2013). I tried them in Ventura (released in 2022) but none do work.

I conclude my testing on my two mac's (10.11.6/El Capitan@2016 and 13.1/Ventura@2022): both provide a GUI switch in Preferences|Common|Shares|RemoteLogin.

You just turn it off and on. sshd will be restarted and read the sshd_config file to reflect your changes.

(Although there are corresponding command-line commands for the two actions, I don't think you bother to know them.)

Comment: In my Ventura this setting is under System Settings > General > Sharing. It was already off, though, and turning it on didn't help.